# Scala Execute List of Futures Concurrently

Tags: scala, concurrency, future

I am new to scala. It is  helping to reduce code and provide the elements of a functional language to deal with data. However, I am having trouble finding a way to execute a lst of futures in parallel. My list is of the type List[Future[String]]. How can I get this list to execute in parallel?

```
val futures=(data.map { x => this.breakString(x) }).toList
```

The Future is defined as:

```
def breakString(inX:Object):Future[String]=Future {
    //get new jsonObject
    val x =inX.asInstanceOf[String]
    val jmap=JacksMapper.readValue[Map[String,AnyRef]](x)
    val dataArr:Array[String]=jmap.get(this.rowcolumn).asInstanceOf[String].split(token)
    val map=dataArr.map { x => (positions.get(dataArr.indexOf(x).asInstanceOf[String]),x) }.toMap
    map.put(hashKey, jmap.get(hashKey).asInstanceOf[String])

    //write out positions
    JacksMapper.writeValueAsString(map)
  }
```

Comment: This seems a little wierd but does it execute in parallel as traverse would appear to execute sequentially?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Future.traverse`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.concurrent.Future$@traverse[A,B,M[X]%3C:TraversableOnce[X]]%28in:M[A]%29%28fn:A=%3Escala.concurrent.Future[B]%29%28implicitcbf:scala.collection.generic.CanBuildFrom[M[A],B,M[B]],implicitexecutor:scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext%29:scala.concurrent.Future[M[B]]).

Quote from the Scala documentation :

> This is useful for performing a parallel map. For example, to apply a function to all items of a list in parallel

```
Future.traverse(data)(breakString)
```

Answer (score 1):

The Futures will begin executing as soon as they have an available thread to run them. Assuming you have an execution context with multiple threads, that means they will automatically execute in parallel.

You can demonstrate this with the Scala REPL:

```
scala> import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.Future

scala> import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

scala> def makeFuture(ms: Int, msg: String): Future[Unit] = Future { Thread.sleep(ms); println(msg) }
makeFuture: (ms: Int, msg: String)scala.concurrent.Future[Unit]

scala> makeFuture(1000, "a"); makeFuture(500, "b")
res2: scala.concurrent.Future[Unit] = scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise@2819f703

scala> b
a
```